# What if the first parameter of every() is not used in JS

Tags: javascript

I was using every function in JS and I decided to not use the first parameter, that is, here is the code:

```
const arr = newValues.every((item, indexOfItem, array) => {
            const nextItem =
                array[indexOfItem + 1] === undefined ? Infinity : array[indexOfItem + 1];
            return array[indexOfItem] < nextItem;
        });
```

As you can see, item parameter is not used, if I remove it, will indexOfItem be considered as index and not item? I mean, I get a warning saying item is declared but never used. So, if I remove item then indexOfItem is considered as item which I want to avoid. Thus, how can I solve this?

Comment: You seem to have answered the question in the last paragraph. I don't understand what more you want.

Comment: Parameters are always passed *by position*. It doesn’t matter what their names are.

Comment: @Quentin, you misunderstood me, I just get a warning item is declared but never used and if I remove it then indexOfItem will be considered as item which I do not want. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @MII instead of `array[indexOfItem]`, use `item`. That should stop that warning. But, you should probably find a way to disable that warning. Many times, you have to declare variables and parameters which you don't use.

Comment: Default functions have predefined structures, with params to be passed and types of params. One can not modify the order for it. If it is there, it is to be there.

You can define your own custom function, with optional params, but again it's different than this. So if you use, every function here, you wrote like **every((item, indexOfItem, array)** or you wrote like **every((a, b, c)** it will consider _a as an item, b as an index of that item and c be the array_.

Comment: @MII — If your question is about stopping your linter complaining when you don't use a specific argument, then you should edit your question to make it about that. As it stands, your question is just an explanation about how arguments are assigned in order.

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1939

Comment: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/eslint/disable-no-unused-vars-for-unused-parameter/

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8661

Comment: @MII Please be more specific on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: typically, you can use an underscore to show an unused argument: `(_, indexOfItem, array) => {`, the first item will always be the item, the second the index, the third the array. So you won't be able to remove the first argument and treat it as the index

Answer (score 1):

If it is your linter (e.g. eslint) giving you the warning, you can just prefix the unused variable name with an underscore to eliminate the warning.

```
const arr = newValues.every((_item, indexOfItem, array) => {
```

If that is not working, you can add this to the eslint config to enable it:

```
eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
```